# Instagram Feed on Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, instagram, feed

I need to create an Instagram feed to fetch data from an Instagram account and to embed it in my site

I have tried to install many widgets but they are neither free to use nor customizable.

I expected an Instagram feed for like 12 pictures in a slideshow.

Comment: If you're not going to use an out-of-the-box solution, you may need to register an account and develop your own using the API

Comment: yes daniel but i thought there might be a fast solution to make this up like in version 2.x ,

Comment: If you have a fast solution from 2.x, why not try port it? At the very least show the working 2.x code and ask for help on porting it. Open questions like this don't usually get answers and are often flagged for deleting